# Is a semigroup always an exponential?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Banach space, $\mathscr{B}(H)=\{T:H\to H: \text{where $T$ is a bounded linear operator}\}$, and $S:[0,\infty)\to \mathscr{B}(H)$, a map with the following properties:
$$
S(0)=I, \quad S(s+t)=S(s)S(t), \quad \text{for all $s,t\in[0,\infty)$},
$$
and
$$
\lim_{t\to s^+}S(t)x=S(s)x, \quad \text{for all $x\in H$.}
$$
Is there a general theorem which allows us to express $S(t)=\exp(tA)$, for a suitable unbounded operator $A$? If yes, what kind of operator is $A$? In particular, what can we tell about its spectrum?

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question is to point you at the Hille-Yosida Theorem and its various cousins. They should be in any standard functional analysis textbook. More can't be said about the spectrum unless you have more detail about the operators $S(t)$.

Comment: The spectrum of $A$ has to be contained in a proper left half-plane.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For every $C_0$-semigroup, $S(t)=\exp(At)$ in the sense that
$$S(t)x=\lim_{n\to\infty} (I-{At\over n})^{-n}x.$$
The relationship between the spectrum of $A$ and the spectrum of $S(t)$ is not quite so straightforward. Pazy's book (Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations) is a good place to start reading about the subject.

Answer (score 3):

To expand the answer of Michael Renardy: your question concerns the important question when can we "insert" an operator into a function and what properties can we deduce from the properties of the function only. This is the main idea behind various "functional calculus concepts", and I recommend the excellent [monograph](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-7643-7698-8) and papers (for example, see [this](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~haase/Homepage_files/semi.pdf) or [this](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~haase/files/bahamu30-05-2012.pdf)) by Markus Haase.

The most widely used is the so-called Hille-Phillips calculus, which is based on Laplace transform techniques. This and the [Post-Widder inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_inversion_formula) makes the connection Michael mentions.